# Web2py SQLForm.grid: Removing the uploaded files saved with original name

Tags: web2py

This is my DB definition.

```
db.define_table('emsAlertTokens',
            Field('emsrelease',default=session.releasefield,writable=False,label=T('Release')),
            Field('emsmachine',default=session.machinefield,writable=False,label=T('Machine')),
            Field('emsstartdate','datetime',default=request.now,label=T('Start Date')),
            Field('emsenddate','datetime',IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message='Please specify the End Date.'), label=T('End Date')),
            Field('errorgrepfile','upload',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message='Please upload a valid error tokens file'),custom_store=ems_file, custom_retrieve=ems_retrieve, autodelete=True, uploadfield=True, uploadfs=None, label=T('Error Tokens')),
            Field('tokenname','string',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY('What would you call your token file?'),label=T('Token File Name')))
```

My Controller:

```
def setemstoken():
query = (db.emsAlertTokens)
headers = {'emsAlertTokens.emsrelease': 'Release', 'emsAlertTokens.emsmachine': 'Machine', 'emsAlertTokens.emsstartdate':'Start Time', 'emsAlertTokens.emsenddate': 'End Time','emsAlertTokens.errorgrepfile': 'Token File'}
upload = lambda filename: URL("ems_download", args=[filename])
grid = SQLFORM.grid(query=query,headers=headers,create=True, upload=upload,user_signature=True, deletable=True, editable=True, maxtextlength=100, paginate=25,formargs=dict(message_onsuccess='Error Filter Set',message_onfailure='Form has errors. Tokens not accepted.'),onvalidation=emsvalidate)
return dict(grid=grid)
```

As can be noticed there is a custom download, retrieve function. This was done to save the file in its original name and that is working fine. The parameter  'autodelete=True' is set for the SQLForm. But as there is a custom retrieving/download function and due to that the physical files are not removed when i am deleting a row from the grid.

Kindly advice me on this, how to include the delete function so that whenever a row is deleted the physical file associated to it is also removed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `autodelete` functionality expects (a) that the upload folder is the default /web2py/applications/yourapp/uploads folder (or otherwise that the "uploadfolder" attribute of the field is specified), and (b) that the value stored in the upload field is the filename that should be appended to the upload folder path. If one or both of these conditions are not met, then you should instead provide a custom delete function via:

```
Field(..., custom_delete=your_custom_function)
```

Be careful using the original filename, as the reason web2py rewrites the filename is to prevent path traversal attacks. Also note that web2py's default behavior does preserve the original filename (via an encoding).